# Construct a string with multiple lines

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I want to create a "leaderboard" into a string. Is this possible ? I have this code, but it doesn`t work..

```
string leaderBoard;
leaderBoard.resize(1024);
leaderBoard.clear();

for (unsigned contor = 0; contor < myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.size(); ++contor){
    leaderBoard += myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.at(contor)->getPlayerName();
    leaderBoard += "-----";
    leaderBoard += to_string(myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.at(contor)->getPlayerScore());
    leaderBoard += '\n';
}
```

It puts into my leaderBoard, only the PlayerName (first line), the other lines just doesn`t modify anything to my string.
Is this possible to create a "leaderboard" into a string ? I want to do this because i need to pass this string to my client through  a socket.

PS: Final string should be only 3 lines.

Comment: " it doesn`t work" Never say that in a question here. Explain what you want, and why your code does not do what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to contain an [mcve]

Comment: "*the other lines just doesn't modify anything to my string*" - yes, they do, just not how you think. You need to use `reserve()` instead of `resize()` (and the `clear()` is redundant either way). "*i need to pass this string to my client through a socket*" - so what is stopping you?  A line-break delimited string is not necessary the best choice for sending the leaderboard, unless your communication protocol is all text-based to begin with. Otherwise, a binary serialization format using integers for the player count, string lengths, scores, etc would be a better choice.

Comment: If i make cout <<  leaderBord it only apperas PlayerName there..

Comment: @Darius [works fine for me](http://ideone.com/lhfCMy)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, it was a problem at my appliaction.. The code works in another cpp file, but when i put it into my app, it doesn`t work anymore. I solved it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  std::stringstream for this ;

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string leaderBoard;
std::stringstream sstream;

for (unsigned contor = 0; contor < myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.size(); ++contor)
{
    sstream << myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.at(contor)->getPlayerName();
    sstream << "-----";
    sstream << to_string(myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom.at(contor)->getPlayerScore());
    sstream << '\n';
}

leaderBoard = sstream.str();
```

Comment: I would suggest using `std::ostringstream` instead. I would also suggest caching `myPlayer->getPlayerRoom()->playersInRoom` to a local reference variable, and `playersInRoom.at(contor)` to another local variable. This will make the code easier to read and maintain.